# Extract numbers from string, put them in array and replace with text in one function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have string that looks like this: |​6|​7|​8|​9|​10|​13|​20|​22​|. I need to turn this string into array of numbers and then based on the numbers return  different text strings. I managed to create this code that basicaly do what I need.

Problem that I have is that I need to execute only one function on the other side that will take string as input and give me text based on numbers in array as output. Could someone please help me with this?

```
function extract_numbers($string)
{
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);

return $match[0];

}
$numbers_array = extract_numbers($string);
if (in_array("6", $numbers_array)) {
    return "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("22", $numbers_array)) {
    return "Got mac";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried explode? http://us3.php.net/explode

Comment: did you want you will pass number array and it will return text array with containing those number in array?

Comment: @MoeTsao well ok that replaces first function, but what code do I need to put after this to replace numbers in array with text? $string = '|​6|​7|​8|​9|​10|​13|​20|​22​|';
print_r(explode('|', $string, -1));

Comment: What kind of text, are there any algorithm or fixed text ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera all will be fixed text as seen in example code

Comment: Which number maps to which text, are there any rules ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes I want to define rules - for example 6 should return text Airbag 2X, 22 should return text Airbag 8X and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you may try this (a little confused about your question)

```
// Map numbers and text
$text = array(6 => 'Airbag 2X', 22 => 'Airbag 8X');

// Explode numbers
$numbers = explode('|', '6|22');

// Check if number exists and then echo it.
if(in_array(22, $numbers)) echo $text[22]; // Airbag 8X
```

You may also use a loop to print out all the numbers:

```
foreach($numbers as $number) echo $text[$number] . '<br />';
```

Output:

```
Airbag 2X
Airbag 8X
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I need to run this for string variable and not only for '6|22'. When I try to replace this line with $numbers = explode('|', $string); it is not working. Any advice on how to modify this for variable as input?

Comment: It should work, update your example that is not working now.wr

Comment: Works `$str = '6|22';$numbers = explode('|', $str);print_r($numbers);`.

Comment: $string = '|​6|​7|​8|​9|​10|​13|​20|​22​|';
$text = array(6 => 'Airbag 2X', 22 => 'Airbag 8X');

$numbers = explode('|', $string);
if(in_array(6, $numbers)) echo $text[22];

Comment: Ok, problem seems to be that in variable are numbers between | from both sides​ insted of one side as in your example. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It's not s problem at all but you may use this `$numbers = explode('|', trim($string, '|'));`.

Comment: [Check this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dQmbXB), check your encoding in the editor.